# Schengen visa approved, cancelled UAE permit

Tags: schengen

I'm a Philippines passport holder, my Schengen visa is approved but I cancel my Dubai residence visa and go back to Philippines after visiting Schengen country, can I I still travel to Schengen country with the Schengen visa but cancel Dubai permit?

Comment: Why not? What has one got to do with the other?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, a travel history helps to *get* the Schengen visa in the first place, so this isn't an absurd question. Still, cancelling the Dubai visa by himself is also part of a normal travel history.